# Add rest authentication using JWT

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

I need to develop rest authentication with jwt.

I know how to take the token from the url but in this case is not from the url. The api generate a response with the jwt but i dont know how to take that jwt from the response

Im trying using IdentityModel but when i try to do this I have an error

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
{
    Address = "https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/token",
    GrantType = "custom",

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    Parameters =
    {
        { "custom_parameter", "custom value"},
        { "scope", "api1" }
    }
});
```

I cannot create that HttpClient and the using that provide VS dont have that methods

Comment: You have to install 2 packages IdentityModel and IdentityModel.AspNetCore. Then, in your controller, add this line: using IdentityModel.Client;

Comment: You need to provide more context, how is the client configurated? have u enabled client credetials flow? and what does the error tell you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try following in a console app:
Install package `Identiy.Model`

```
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // from discoverydocument to get token endpoint information
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001"); //identity server URL
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disco.AuthorizeEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine(disco.TokenEndpoint);
        }

        // request for client-flow token
        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

            ClientId = "client",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "api2",
            //GrantType ="client_credentials",
 
        });

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);



        // use token to access api
        var apiClient = new HttpClient();
        apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

        var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7171/identity");   //the api protected by [Authorize]
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }

    }
```